# Classifier issue when creating ArrayList

Tags: android, for-loop, android-fragments, arraylist, kotlin

I'm trying to create a `for-loop` to generate items in an `ArrayList`, but I'm not sure why this 'companion object' error appears in this scenario. `Product` in `val product = Product` returns an error:

> Classifier does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here

**inside fragment**

```
    val items = resources.getStringArray(R.array.product_names)
    val itemDescriptions = resources.getStringArray(R.array.product_descriptions)
    for (n in items.indices) {
        val product = Product
        product.productName(items[n])
        product.productDescription(itemDescriptions[n])
        productList.add(product)
    }
```

**Product class**

```
class Product {

    var productName: String? = null
    var productDescription: String? = null

    constructor() {}

    constructor(productName: String, productDescription: String) {
        this.productName = productName
        this.productDescription = productDescription
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to instantiate your `Product` class like this:

```
val product = Product()
```

Notice the parentheses that correspond to this:

```
// ...
constructor() {} // empty secondary constructor of Product
// ...
```

**Note:**

You don't use Kotlin to its full potential. Take a look at the following refactorings:

1. `Product` class:

   ```
   class Product(val productName: String, val productDescription: String)
   ```

You can declare properties in the primary constructor.

2. for loop

   ```
   val productList = items.mapIndexed { index, item ->
       Product(item, itemDescriptions[index])
   }
   ```

You can transform items to a list of Products using [`mapIndexed`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-indexed.html).

Answer (score 0):

To create a new instance of `Product`, you must use the corresponding constructor `Product()` instead. Just using `Product` makes the compiler think you are trying to work with its [companion object](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#companion-objects), which it does not have. The following is part of the Kotlin [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#creating-instances-of-classes):

> To create an instance of a class, we call the constructor as if it were a regular function:
>
> ```
> val invoice = Invoice()
>
> val customer = Customer("Joe Smith")
> ```
>
> Note that Kotlin does not have a `new` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `for` loop in each iteration you have to "create" a `Product` object by passing to the constructor the corresponding items from the arrays `items` and `itemDescriptions` and then add this object to the list:

```
val items = resources.getStringArray(R.array.product_names)
val itemDescriptions = resources.getStringArray(R.array.product_descriptions)
for (n in items.indices) {
    val product = Product(items[n], itemDescriptions[n])
    productList.add(product)
}
```

this loop can also be written like:

```
items.indices.forEach { productList.add(Product(items[it], itemDescriptions[it])) }
```